# What is that jQuery thing called Mashable uses for their top 5 images/videos posts?

Tags: jquery, css, image

Mashable added this image scroller thing a while back and I want it for a new project:

http://mashable.com/2012/01/28/funny-gifs/

That's it in action there, but what is it?

Is it available as a WP plug-in?

Comment: The source is available on that site. Have you tried reading it? Included libraries should be relatively simple to identify.

Comment: I'm not very good at finding these or what exactly to look for.. wha should I e looking for? thanks

Comment: Without some idea as to what you're looking for it will be quite difficult.  Since it sounds like you're looking for a WP plugin, I think you'd save yourself quite a bit of time by looking for a plugin first.  Given the popularity of this style of presentation, I'm sure that you will be able to find something similar by searching the plugin directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for a "Carousel"

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=carousel